# How do I host multiple hidden services? (Multiple addresses)

Tags: configuration, onion-services, web-hosting

I have the same basic issue as [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-am-i-doing-wrong-attempting-to-host-multiple-tor-hidden-services-on-one-se) but it wasn't resolved. I have one functioning service, everything runs fine:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test1/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:44403
```

If I attempt to add another HiddenServiceDir directive like this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test1/
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:44403
```

The service in /test1/ fails to connect, but /test2/ loads fine. If I switch the HiddenServiceDir lines around, the top one fails but the second one works fine.
My lighttpd config looks like this:

```
server.document-root = "/var/www/tor/lighttpddefault/files" 
server.port = 44401

$SERVER["socket"] == ":44403" { 
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.onion$" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/tor/test1/files" 
  }
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\.onion$" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/tor/test2/files" 
  }
}
```

To answer the questions in the linked question; Tor starts successfully each time, does not throw any error messages. Both directories have the same permission. All keys are Tor generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HiddenServicePort corresponds to the most recent HiddenServiceDir entry.

> ```
>   HiddenServicePort VIRTPORT [TARGET]
>        Configure a virtual port VIRTPORT for a hidden service. You may use this option multiple times; each time applies to the service using the most recent
>        HiddenServiceDir. By default, this option maps the virtual port to the same port on 127.0.0.1 over TCP. You may override the target port, address, or both
>        by specifying a target of addr, port, addr:port, or unix:path. (You can specify an IPv6 target as [addr]:port.) You may also have multiple lines with the
>        same VIRTPORT: when a user connects to that VIRTPORT, one of the TARGETs from those lines will be chosen at random.
> ```

So something like this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test1/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:44403
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/tor/test2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:44403
```

Also you shouldn't be putting your private keys in `/var/www`, put them in `/var/lib/tor`. The httpd doesn't need to and shouldn't be able to read the private keys for the onion. Only the user that `tor` is running as should have access, following the [principle of least authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Comment: I feel pretty stupid, thats seems obvious. Much thanks