# Multiple hidden services on one server

Tags: configuration, onion-services, onion-routing, network-configuration

How is it that I can host multiple (static) hidden services on one server?
I am just needing 3 simple and static HTML sites with their own .onion?
If I add multiple HiddenServiceDir do they have to be on different ports or can they be on the same? There will not be a large amount of traffic going to the hidden services.

Comment: Yes you can host multiple hidden services with multiple `HiddenServiceDir` and `HiddenServicePort` lines. They can run either on the same port or different ports depending on how you have your web server set up. For example: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12324/how-do-i-host-multiple-hidden-services-multiple-addresses

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host multiple hidden services on the same server.
Your torrc file should have this content added for each site -:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service1
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service2
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

In case of ubuntu or debian if you are using apache2 add the following lines to your /etc/apache2/site-available/00-default.conf file -:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourhiddenservice1domain.onion
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/firstsite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourhiddenservice2domain.onion
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secondsite
</VirtualHost>
```

And you are done!